# Genesis - How display the latest posts in 1 column instead of 2?

Tags: wordpress, genesis

[The Minimum Pro Theme](https://my.studiopress.com/themes/minimum/#demo-full) seems to display the latest posts divided into 2 columns by default, and although it seemed like an easy task, I could not find any way to change it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try overwriting the template file in your child theme? You are pretty much free to modify the "archive" pages as much as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update **100% working**:

Set width `width: 100%;` in your theme's style.css file.

**style.css**

```
.genesis-grid-even, .genesis-grid-odd {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Completely forgot about the CSS